# Duplicate values in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following format:

```
{ 'a' : [1], 'b' : [1,2,3], 'c' : [1,1,2], 'd' : [2,3,4] }
```

and I want to create a list of the keys which have a '1' in their values.

So my result list should look like:

```
['a','b','c','c']
```

I cannot understand how to work with duplicate values.
Any ideas how can I get such a list?

Comment: Loop through the list in the property. For each time you see `1`, append the property name to the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions

```
>>> d = { 'a' : [1], 'b' : [1,2,3], 'c' : [1,1,2], 'd' : [2,3,4] }
>>> [key for key, values in d.items() for element in values if element==1]
['c', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Here we have two nested for loops in our list comprehension. The first iterate over each key, values pairs in the dictionary and the second loop iterate over each element in the "value" list and return the key each time that element equal to `1`. The result list is unordered because dict are unordered which means there are no guarantees about the order of the items.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
>>> x = { 'a' : [1], 'b' : [1,2,3], 'c' : [1,1,2], 'd' : [2,3,4] }
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([k]*v.count(1) for k, v in x.iteritems() if 1 in v))
['a', 'c', 'c', 'b']
```

If using Python 3, use `items` instead of `iteritems`.

Answer (score 2):

This uses two loops, `k,v in d.items()` which gets each (key,value) pair from the dictionary, and `n in v` which loops through each value in `v`:

```
d = { 'a' : [1], 'b' : [1,2,3], 'c' : [1,1,2], 'd' : [2,3,4] }
l = []
for k,v in d.items():
    for n in v:
        if n == 1:
            l.append(k)
l.sort()
```

If you want a one-liner:

```
l = sorted(k for k,v in d.items() for n in v if n == 1)
```

Comment: You said you don't know how to rollback so why rollback my edit?

Comment: The rollback button wasn't there until I refreshed the page.  I'll stop making edits, you can make yours now.

Comment: You should remove the one-liner solution from your answer.

Comment: This answer is meant to show the solution in a full stepwise program and again in a compact, pythonic one-liner that does the same thing.  Don't delete my answer.

Comment: My answer also sorts the results on the same line, which makes it different than your answer.

Comment: @user3100115, please stop removing the 1-line solution -- the author of this post has made it clear that they want to include that code in the answer.

Comment: @josilber please see the edit history. Perhaps you will understand why I edited the first place..

Comment: @user3100115 It looks like you came up with similar solutions within a minute of each other, which usually isn't a case of somebody copying the other.

Answer (score 2):

easy way: (Python 3)

```
d = { 'a' : [1], 'b' : [1,2,3], 'c' : [1,1,2], 'd' : [2,3,4] }  
n = 1
result = []
for key, value in d.items():
    for i in value.count(n):
        res.append(key)
```

if you want list sorted than:

```
result.sort()
```

Answer (score 2):

The sort must be made on the dictionary to get the expected result. This should work:

```
list = []
for i in sorted(d.keys()):
   list+=[i for x in d[i] if x == 1]
print list
```

will output:

```
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```